# Java Applet sandbox security, local vs external access

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet, sandbox

I had a bug in our (code signed) java applet "access denied (java.net.SocketPermission x.x.x.x:443 connect_resolve." We had an html "save" button that was calling (via javascript) an applet method to save a file, loaded into the applet, onto the webserver. After some extensive google research, I fixed it by wrapping our applet's save method code in doPrivileged(). Bug seems to be fixed, people are happy.

I want to confirm that I completely understand the original circumstances and the solution I applied (backwards, I know, but turn around time didn't allow me to really research the issue).

Whats specifically confusing me is that we tested our applet on a test server in our in-house network extensively and never got this error until we attempted the javascript "save" button from a client machine external to our network. So at this point, I'm just making an educated guess: that is how the java applet sandbox mechanism works.

Is this true? As long as the client applet is accessing web server resources from a client machine that is within the same domain network it is considered within the sandbox walls? And if the client machine is external to the web-server's local network the applet request is considered outside of the sandbox walls and needs the doPrivileged? Or is there another explanation here that I am missing?

I haven't been able to find anything in sun's documentation or through google that specifically proves or disproves my assertion. Clarification from someone with more experience in java applets is greatly appreciated

Comment: By default an applet is only supposed to connect to the server it was downloaded from. So I guess that's why you needed a privileged action, but it's only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As long as the client applet is accessing web server resources from a client machine that is within the same domain network it is considered within the sandbox walls?

If by that, you mean a sand-boxed applet can 'phone home' to its own server, then yes.

> And if the client machine is external to the web-server's local network the applet request is considered outside of the sandbox walls and needs the doPrivileged?

An applet needs trust (digitally signed + accepted by the end user) to access resources from other servers.  The thing that further complicates it is the JavaScript.  Suddenly there is an 'untrusted' element to be considered by the JRE.  By wrapping the code in the doPrivileged() method we are saying to the JRE that this code is to be trusted even if called by something else such as JS.

Comment: So I guess what I'm asking is, does an applet assume this trust if it is on the same local network as the web server it "belongs to"?  Originally I would not get this error when I clicked our javascript save button from my work machine which is on the same network as our webserver. But, I would get the error if I clicked our javascript save button from my home machine, which is not on the same network as the webserver. Thank you for the quick help, very appreciated!

Comment: The answer to our question is 'yes' the JRE assumes it is OK.  I do not think that even JS interaction would be a problem there (as suggested by your report).

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much for helping me get a grip on all this!