# Signed Applet With Javascript Function Call: Initialization Error on IcedTea plugin

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet, japplet

I'm trying to call a Javascript function from inside a Java Signed Applet that I developed. This goes pretty well when I use a browser with Sun Java plugin. I tested on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 with Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer (Windows) browsers.

When I try to run the same code on any browser with Iced Tea plugin the following error is informed:

---

> net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize applet. 
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:735)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:676)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:886)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getPermissions(JNLPClassLoader.java:915)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1499)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1526)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1341)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1952)
>       at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:6190)
>       at java.awt.Component.access$500(Component.java:188)
>       at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6144)
>       at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6142)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:6141)
>       at java.awt.Component.(Component.java:6110)
>       at java.awt.Container.(Container.java:276)
>       at java.awt.Panel.(Panel.java:64)
>       at java.awt.Panel.(Panel.java:56)
>       at java.applet.Applet.(Applet.java:65)
>       at javax.swing.JApplet.(JApplet.java:130)
>       at br.ufrj.land.tangram.measures.NetworkMeasurerApplet.(NetworkMeasurerApplet.java:11)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:726)
>       ... 2 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getPermissions(JNLPClassLoader.java:915)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1499)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1526)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1341)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1952)
>       at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:6190)
>       at java.awt.Component.access$500(Component.java:188)
>       at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6144)
>       at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6142)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:6141)
>       at java.awt.Component.(Component.java:6110)
>       at java.awt.Container.(Container.java:276)
>       at java.awt.Panel.(Panel.java:64)
>       at java.awt.Panel.(Panel.java:56)
>       at java.applet.Applet.(Applet.java:65)
>       at javax.swing.JApplet.(JApplet.java:130)
>       at br.ufrj.land.tangram.measures.NetworkMeasurerApplet.(NetworkMeasurerApplet.java:11)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:726)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:676)
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:886)java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.runLoader(NetxPanel.java:154)
>       at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:379)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:429) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

---

### Configurations and Things that I tried:

- The Linux flavor that I'm using with Iced Tea plugin is Ubuntu 12.04
- I tried compiling my code with Sun JDK 6 and 7 and Open JDK 6 and 7 but both fail with Iced Tea plugin on browsers.
- I tried my code with Iced Tea version 6 and version 7
- I tried my code with Firefox and Chrome browsers on my Ubuntu

### Code snippets:

HTML (inside body tag):

```
    <!-- JavaScript File That Contains My Javascript Function -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my_javascript_file.js"></script>

    <!-- Applet That Will Call My Javascript Function -->
    <object height="1" width="1" id="MyApplet" name="MyApplet"
    java_version="1.5+" type="application/x-java-applet">
        <param name="code" value="foo.MyApplet" />
        <param name="archive" value="MyApplet.jar" />
        <param name="JVM_PARAM" value="-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy" />
        <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
        <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
        <param name="name" value="MyApplet" />
    </object>
```

Javascript method that i'm trying to call (inside my_javascript_file.js):

```
window.performAppletCode = function (parameter_1) {
    //Function code
}
```

Java applet code (relevant part) inside "MyApplet.jar":

```
package foo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import netscape.javascript.JSException;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet {

    //Parameter that will be sent to Javascript function    
    public String parameter_1;    
    //JSObject that will be responsible for accessing javascript on my page 
    public JSObject window = null;
    private Thread myThread;
    private ImportantClass importantClassInstance;

    @Override
    public void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (this.window == null) {
            try {
                this.window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
                if (this.window == null){
                    System.out.println("Window is null");
                }
            }
            catch (JSException jse) {
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
            fooStart();
        }
    }


    public void fooStart() {

            importantClassInstance = new ImportantClass();

            // MyThread Section
            myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Run latency test.
                    int[] fooArray = importantClassInstance.fooMethod();
                    parameter_1 = Arrays.toString(fooArray);
                    //Javascript function call
                    window.call("performAppletCode", new Object[] {parameter_1});
                }
            });
            myThread.start();
    }
}
```

My applet is signed using jarsigner and the certificate is included on my HTML directory.

If anyone knows a possible clue to solving this problem, please, let me know.

Thanks,
Guilherme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, but I sill don't know why this happens. Here's the thing:

When I start my web page (with the applet and everything else) from a directory that it's located on my OS Ubuntu, that crazy error pops up on my Java console. BUT when I start my page from a directory that it's located on a remote server (e.g. another computer in my home LAN) everything works perfect. So, for some reason, I need to request my own page from some remote server to everything work OK. This only happens with the above situation described on my question. I will search on the web trying to find why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

When called from JS, an applet loses trust.  To fix that, see `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856542/418556).

Comment: But the Applet is the one that is calling a Javascript function. The javascript function is not calling anything from Java Applet. doPrivileged() is still necessary?

Comment: Well, I did some search about doPrivileged() and saw the answer above. This really does not fit on the case Java calling Javascript function...

Comment: Huh.. did not notice it was Java calling JS.  My expectation (same as yours) is the `AccessController` becomes irrelevant there.  Let me think more about it..  BTW - please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the Java & JS code, as well as a link to where others can see the applet.